# How to manually create Proxy for Detail Collection in NHibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate, collections, proxy

I've got class, let it be Foo:

```
public class Foo
{ 
  ...

  protected MyCollection<Detail> _details
  public virtual MyCollection<Detail> Details 
  {
     get { return _details ?? new MyCollection<Details>(); }
     set { _details = value; ... } 
  }
  ...
}

public class Detail {...}
```

When I do LINQ query:

```
var q = session.Query<Foo>().Select(foo => new Foo( property1 = foo.property1, ... );
...
q.ToList();
```

I've got **NULL** in _details field, and *when I access to **Details*** to get all **Lazy** details, of course I get *new MyCollection()*, but not IPersistentBag (or else, IPersistentCollection).

So How can I manually create proxy collection (I've got session / sessionFactory references)?

[ Added ] here is the mappings (on Foo):

```
<bag name="Details" lazy="true" collection-type="NHibernateDataService.DetailBag`1[[DataObjects.Detail, DataObjects]], NHibernateDataService" cascade="all-delete-orphan" fetch="select" batch-size="1" access="property" inverse="true">
  <key column="`Master`" />
  <one-to-many class="DataObjects.Detail" />
</bag>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What don't you use a field initializer for _details? If you add items to a new Foo, _details will remain null.

Comment: because of our business logic - we move objects through Wcf wire all the time, from server 2 client and back, and we don't want to care about them =)

Answer (score 0):

MyCollection can't be mapped to IPersistentBag, unless, of course, you implement that interface on MyCollection (and probably set the mapping type explicitly??)...

A more standard approach is to set the "collection-type" property on the bag mapping to a custom type - an implementation of IUserCollectionType, which you can choose to make a base class that MyCollection derives from.

Comment: I was wrong
Yeap, you are right, It implements IUserCollectionType;